# iCloud container name is not displayed proper in development App

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-documents

In the application iCloud integration but in the container, it displays the name of the bundle that owns the container.

- Configuration iCloud capability from developer account
- Enable iCloud capability from Xcode
- Added keys and value into info.plist file as below

  ```
  <key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
     <dict>
         <key>iCloud.com.example.applepaydemo</key>
         <dict>
             <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
             <string>Apple Demo</string>
             <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
             <true/>
             <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
             <string>Any</string>
         </dict>
     </dict>
  ```

Issue: It displays **applepaydemo** name of container not **Apple Demo** in iCloud Manage Account Storage

Comment: did you find an answer? im getting the same issue in iOS17

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.